Get session ID for current interactive user from session 0 on shared desktop (i.e Citrix session)
I'm trying to get the session ID of the current interactive user.  But it must work in a shared desktop scenario such as Citrix, when invoked from a hidden session 0.
I've got a couple of issues.

In a shared desktop scenario, there may be multiple "Active" sessions (if you run "query session" for example, you will see multiple active sessions).  Therefore enumerating sessions (WTSEnumerateSessions) to find an "active" session probably wont work unless you know who the current active user for the current session is!  And I'm not sure how to find this.

It also needs to be able to run from Session 0 (i.e. hidden).  As an example, if the active user is running in session 2 but I am running my code from a hidden session 0, I need to return session 2.


I can retrieve the session ID when running from outside session 0.  This is the code I've used:
public static uint GetCurrentSessionId()
{
    uint sessionId;
    uint processId = (uint)System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
    if (!ProcessIdToSessionId(processId, out sessionId))
    {
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
    return sessionId;
}

But if I use this in hidden mode, System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id gets the process ID of the current process running in session 0, so it won't work even if I call WTSQueryUserToken afterwards.
Any pointers appreciated!

can be several active interactive sessions. 1 Console and several rdp. so what you mean under current interactive user

Let's assume I, as a standard user, am working on a desktop (RDP/ICA) session (session 2, for example).  And my executable (running as a service) invokes a hidden process as the SYSTEM account that runs in session 0.  I want my executable to get the SID of the standard user working on the desktop.  And for that, presumably I need to somehow know the session the user is working on?

but can be several interactive sessions. several different users

Yes, which is my challenge. How does an exe/service running in session 0 do anything in a user context? Or read user information such as a Sid?

what user ?? can be several users

I'm basically trying to run this cmdlet using the usersid parameter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appvclient/publish-appvclientpackage?view=windowsserver2025-ps but it must run elevated and pass the current user Sid as the parameter. Not sure how I can invoke it in a shared desktop.

how desktop here related at all ? why you suddenly want exec something ? based on what event ?

A shared desktop/session. It might run as a scheduled task on an interval, as the system account.

no, in what question at all ?

Simple example. Let's say the service runs in session 0, when a user manually runs, it pops up a message (outside of session 0 and in the users current session)  saying "you are in session 2". But another user stops and starts the service and it pops up with "you are in session 3". Etc. how can a session 0 service running as SYSTEM determine the session ID of the user starting the service, so it can display a message in that user's session.

Can be multiple users at once. User not start service.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
